# Google Drive MIME types iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-drive-api

I'm trying to integrate Google Drive API with my iOS application. I'm unable to download files, however, and I think it has to do with the MIME type. In the API console I set the MIME types like so:

[image]

And I download files with the following code:

```
GTLQueryDrive *query = [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesList];
query.q = @"mimeType = 'text/plain'";

[self.driveService executeQuery:query completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
                                                          GTLDriveFileList *files,
                                                          NSError *error) {
    if (error == nil) {
        if (self.googleDriveFiles == nil) {
            self.googleDriveFiles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        }
        [self.googleDriveFiles removeAllObjects];
        [self.googleDriveFiles addObjectsFromArray:files.items];
        NSLog(@"files: %@",self.googleDriveFiles);
        [self.noteTableview reloadData];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"An error occurred: %@", error);
        //[DrEditUtilities showErrorMessageWithTitle:@"Unable to load files"
        //                                   message:[error description]
        //                                 delegate:self];
    }
}];
```

`NSLog` outputs `(null)` What's wrong here?

Comment: The configuration screen you posted is only required when you want to [integrate with the Drive UI](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/enable-sdk) and are not related to simply downloading files. Have you been able to get the [Dr. Edit iOS sample](https://github.com/googledrive/dredit/tree/master/objectivec) to work as-is?

Comment: @EricKoleda oh well that's very useful information, thanks. And no, that is exactly what I'm struggling to do. I've implemented the Dr. Edit iOS Sample line by line, but it still won't download any files. Do you have any idea why this might be? I created a .txt file in my drive folder so I would assume that it would be downloaded, no?

Comment: Perhaps try downloading the complete source of the sample instead of building it line-by-line, since you might have missed something.